# Why higher voltage in an electric transmission line should have higher corona effect?

Tags: electrostatics

In an electric transmission line, higher voltage corresponds to lower current (power being more or less equal). Current in the line represents the amount of charge (coulombs) per sec. So, lower current means less amount of charge.
The electric field strength around the current carrying conductor depends on the quantity of the charge. The corona effect in a transmission line depends of strength of the electric field around the conductor.
Why is it mentioned in most literatures that higher transmission line voltages cause more corona effect (which is bad for the transmission system)?
Am I missing something fundamental?

Answer (score 0):

> In an electric transmission line, higher voltage corresponds to lower current (power being more or less equal).

Correct.

> Current in the line represents the amount of charge (coulombs) per sec.

Current representing the flow of charge. It does not include static charging.

> So, lower current means less amount of charge.

No. Lower current means less charge flows through the conductor. A higher voltage on the transmission line means a larger electric field between the transmission line and adjacent objects (i.e., earth or ground) which effectively acts as a capacitor. Thus, higher voltage, higher electric fields, more static charge.

> The electric field strength around the current carrying conductor depends on the quantity of the charge.

Yes, the static charge.

> The corona effect in a transmission line depends of strength of the electric field around the conductor.

Correct. Specifically, the electric field has to be greater than the dielectric breakdown field for the material (in most cases, air).

> Why is it mentioned in most literatures that higher transmission line voltages cause more corona effect (which is bad for the transmission system)? Am I missing something fundamental?

High voltage means more static charging; a larger electric field between the transmission line and its surroundings. As I mentioned, think of the transmission line as one electrode of a capacitor, the other being ground, for example. For a sufficiently large voltage (and hence electric field between the conductor and ground), the air may breakdown into a coronal discharge.

> Am I missing something fundamental?

I believe you are conflating electrostatics with magnetostatics.

Comment: Does the higher voltage have any relation to the charge flowing through the conductor? If not, what does the higher voltage really mean? (As I understand, capacitance of the line is purely a function of the geometry of the transmission line)

Comment: You have a wire (transmission line). You apply a large voltage across that line to drive current along that line; the electric field associated with charge motion goes along the wire (it is not a perfect conductor). There is a current-voltage relationship there. But at the same time, there is a voltage between the conductor and earth (as opposed to the voltage across the wire). This means there is an electric field orthogonal to direction of current flow, and hence charge buildup. So the voltage relates to both, in different ways.